# Can I use several bluetooth headsets?

Tags: windows, bluetooth

[image]

I want to watch movies with my friends. It seems that I can select one device as default audio.

What about if I want to watch with my friends?

Comment: Search google for *bluetooth headphone splitter*. That's what you need. But I haven't seen one that offers more than 2 x connections though.

Comment: OK *maybe* Windows can do this after all... try https://youtu.be/BNhGRSc4oY0